# How can I find contract Android work?

Tags: freelancing, android

Two years ago, following 15+ years in Win32 and SymbianOS, I decided to intensively focus on Android. I took the best part of 2009 off work to learn the new platform thoroughly, and that seems to have been a good strategic decision: Android is everywhere now.

But it seems strangely hard to find Android development work. I have this nagging feeling that there must be some website, some secret society or labour exchange, that has somehow eluded me.

What's going on? If you're an Android contractor, how did you find your current work?

Comment: Are you advertising in any form?

Comment: Not yet... is there anywhere I *should* be advertising? Or just create an Adwords account?

Answer (score 5):

**Start your own Android consultancy**

Since you appear to be in the UK, you may wish to do the following...

**Initial toe-dipping**

1. Create some demonstration Android applications in your spare time and ensure that you have a **very efficient process for generating them** (1 minute to have a full-featured template app to present is about right)
2. Invent a name for yourself and build a very simple website detailing your portfolio.
3. Find yourself a good graphics person (unless you're a great programmer with awesome Photoshop skills)
4. Put the word out that you're available for Android work (Twitter, Facebook, LinkedIn etc). This works best if you've already built a name for yourself selling your own apps (you can add a note in the About section stating your willingness to consider other projects).

Depending on the temperature of the response, you may need to set yourself up with a company

**The icy plunge**

1. Create a limited company (should cost about £90)
2. Get yourself an accountant
3. Get yourself a business account
4. Start accepting cheques

After that, you're in the realms of general business advice.

Comment: Oh I have a pretty solid Android portfolio already, including one that's been Market-featured for the past 8 months. It just doesn't seem to translate into paid work that easily. :)  I think maybe taking a week or two out to build a website and think about self-promotion a bit might be the key. Many thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Reuben It seems that you're into the self-marketing phase. Take a look at Yaro Starak's entrepreneur's journey for a lot of free information about self-promotion

Answer (score 3):

Most Android jobs for programmers I know of are made either by:

- starting your own firm that creates android apps and hype it as much as you can
- join a software development contractor/consultancy firm with close ties to the telecom industry

The common denominator between both forms of company is the sales guy who sell Android services or projects to companies that at first does not have the resources to hire Android guys.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I already work for a consultancy, but as a permie. They charge me out to their clients at ~£500 per day, almost every day. And there's never a shortage of clients. Clearly I need to start my own consultancy...

Answer (score 0):

You can also seek out companies that have Mobile apps on other OSes(iphone, blackberry, windows etc...) Or offer a service on their mobile site that could benefit from being made into a native app and offer to make them an Android version. Thats how I found my first contract work. I found 5 or 6 companies that all offered a similar service which was renting out PDAs with some of their software on them. I sent emails to all of them offering to bring their service to Android and got replies from a few, and an offer from one. You'll certainly have to invest more time in picking up work with this method but if you get in touch with enough people a few are bound to need your service =).